# I'm facing an error during combineReducers in react js with redux

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting following error message when try to combine reducers.

```
// Combining the reducers
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import BlogReducer from './blogReducer';
import CounterReducer from './counterReducer';

const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
    blogposts: BlogReducer,
    counter: CounterReducer
}); 

export default combinedReducer;
// export default BlogReducer;
```

**Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {blogposts, counter}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

Here is the complete code:
https://github.com/shrikant9907/react_starter

Comment: The message is quite explicit. Somewhere you are rendering an object, something probably like `<div>{objectFromRedux}</div>`

Comment: How do you use that `combinedReducer` then ?

Comment: Both the components working correctly. If I export the reducer directly. 

```
export default BlogReducer;
// export default CounterReducer;

```

Is there any issue with combining reducer?

Comment: I'm trying to use the combinedReducer but for both the reducers but it not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not actually the reducer but the render function of the Counter2 component. You're trying to render the entire store that consists of blogposts and the counter.

To fix this, change your `counter2container`'s `mapStateToProps` to something like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    counter: state.counter,
  }
}
```